# If statement trouble - python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, if-statement

I am trying to loop with some if statements but seem to be having trouble with getting the loop to 'break' if I input the wrong name. Right now the options are Chicago, New York, and Washington. I want the code to break and output 'oopsie' if I input the wrong city. Right now it does output 'oopsie' but only after I input the city and month. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for the messy code.

```
def common_day1(city, month):
    city = input("Enter city: ")
    month = int(input("Enter Month: "))
    city_month = df_merged[['City','Month','Day']]
    if city == "Chicago":
        if month == 1:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 1)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 2:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 2)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 3:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 3)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 4:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 4)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 5:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 5)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 6:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'CHI') & (city_month['Month'] == 6)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
    elif city == "New York":
        if month == 1:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 1)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 2:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 2)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 3:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 3)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 4:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 4)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 5:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 5)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 6:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'NYC') & (city_month['Month'] == 6)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
    elif city == "Washington":
        if month == 1:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 1)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 2:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 2)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 3:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 3)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 4:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 4)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 5:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 5)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
        elif month == 6:
            city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == 'WAS') & (city_month['Month'] == 6)]
            common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
            print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city,month,common_day))
    else:
        print("oopsie")
```

Comment: _If statement trouble..._ The whole code is a big trouble...

Comment: what's the input that is giving troubles?

Comment: "Right now it does output 'oopsie' but only after I input the city and month.": Your method prompts the user to input the city and month before it tests the value of city. What do you expect to be different?

Comment: You do not loop with 'if', you branch with 'if'. If you want to loop, use for, while etc. Nor are you using recursion to be able to claim looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking in the `city` and `month` as arguments, then immediately reassigning them based on user input, so what you pass to the function is ignored.

Your code has no loops, I assume you mean the program halts when run, this would be because it is waiting for user input

Also, you are copying the same code a lot of times, you can extract this code to make it easier to read and understand.

Give this a try:

```
def common_day1(city: str, month: int):
    city_month = df_merged[['City', 'Month', 'Day']]
    city_map = {
        "Chicago": "CHI",
        "New York": "NYC",
        "Washington": "WAS"
    }
    if city in city_map.keys() and 0 < month < 6:
        city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City'] == city_map[city]) & (city_month['Month'] == month)]
        common_day = city_month['Day'].value_counts().argmax()
        print("The most common day for {} during {} is {}.".format(city, month, common_day))
    else:
        print("oopsie")


city = input("Enter city: ")
month = int(input("Enter Month: "))
common_day1(city, month)
```

Comment: This worked great! Really helped me shorten my code and made my life much easier haha

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is too difficult to say. It might be you are using the word city both as a local variable and as a input parameter.

I don't understand why you are passing the city as input and then ask the user to input the city again.

You should clean your code and group together the common instructions for example:

```
def common_day1(city, month):
    cities = ["Chicago", " New York"]
    if city not in cities:
        print("oopsie")
        return
    city_month = city_month.loc[(city_month['City']
    if city =="Chicago":
         city_month = (city_month == "CHI") & city_month==...
```